# Button attribute automatically added in ajax response

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

**data-orignal-text** automatically added in ajax success, Here is my code before

```
 <button type="submit" disabled class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block loader" id="idBtn">Verify</button>
```

```
    $(document).on("submit", "#formVerify", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
        var form = $(this);
        BtnLoading();
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: form.action,
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (response)
            {
                if (response.status == 1) {
                    if(response.user_role == 1) {
                        window.location.href = globalSiteUrl + "/admin/dashboard";
                    }else if(response.user_role == 3){
                        window.location.href = globalSiteUrl + "/admin/user_match";
                    }else{
                        window.location.href = globalSiteUrl + "/admin/dashboard";
                    }
                } else {
                    $('#idAlertErrorMsg').show()
                    $('#idScriptErrorMsg').html(response.message)
                    alert_message_fadeout();
                }
                BtnReset();

            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Here after response output is

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block loader" id="idBtn" data-orignal-text="Verify">Verify</button>
```

I want to remove data-orignal-text in button after ajax success.

Answer (score 1):

To multiple issues on the page :

```
var button = document.querySelectorAll('[data-orignal-text="Verify"]');
 button.forEach(element => {
  element.removeAttribute('data-orignal-text');
 })
```

Just for one button issue :

```
var button = document.querySelector('[data-orignal-text="Verify"]');
element.removeAttribute('data-orignal-text');
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked you're code there is no `data-orignal-text` attribute for the button in AJAX success or reject, can you more explain? because its redirects to the URL after ajax success or shows a popup message.

But if you want to remove the attribute from the button then simply write the JQuery code I mention below:

```
$('button').removeAttribute('data-orignal-text');
```

Comment: It's automatically  added in  button attributes  'data-orignal-text'

Comment: used : $('button').removeAttribute('data-orignal-text');